# Ruby on Rails: Migrations: how do I merge to tables into a new table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

i have two tables
attachments:

```
name, doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, cat
```

and media:

```
name, doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, cat
```

how do I write a migration file such that it takes all the entries from both tables and puts them into a new `Files` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MergeAttachmentsMediaToFiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :files do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
      # ...
    end

    Attachment.find(:all).each do |attachment|
      File.create(:name => attachment.name,
                  :doc_name => attachment.doc_name,
                  :doc_type => attachment.doc_type,
                  :doc_size => attachment.doc_size,
                  :cat => attachment.cat)
    end

    # do similar for Media
  end


end
```

Comment: so the question that led me here was "does it make sense to put that rails code in this migration? I've seen people put it in a subsequent migration, other people put it in a seed file, and still others create a one time rake task. I'm not sure what the right answer is :P

Comment: Two migrations might be safer, as it gives more control between creating the table and populating it.  I wouldn't use a rake task, that seems like it could be missed in the deployment. I'm not sure if any one way is "right", but there probably is a Rails Way.

Comment: That's where I arrived as well, for pretty much the same reason. In general I like migrations to be structural, but the world isn't perfect and I've worked a few places where the deployment issue you mention was a huge problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would accomplish this primarily with SQL.  Making some assumptions about your data types:

```
class CreateFiles < ActiveRecord::Migration

 def self.up
  create_table :files do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :doc_name
   t.string :doc_type
   t.integer :doc_size
   t.string :cat
  end

  execute ("insert into files select * from attachments");
  execute ("insert into files select * from media");
 end

 def self.down
  drop_table :files
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the SQL to do it.

```
    def self.up
          create_table :files do |t|
            t.string  :name
            t.string  :doc_name
            t.string  :doc_type
            t.string  :doc_size
            t.string :cat
          end

          execute "INSERT INTO create_table(name, doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, cat)
                   SELECT name, doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, cat FROM attachments
                   UNION
                   SELECT name, doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, cat FROM media"

          drop_table :attachments
          drop_table :media
end
```

Not tested but should work.

Comment: I don't know if I'd drop the old tables... awfully hard to roll back that migration and get your old data back.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to live on the edge. :) But that's true, I only put it in in the name of completeness.